# Send email doesn't work on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I use Belowe code to Send Email .It's work fine when I test it on local but when I upload site on the Server and test it ,it isn't send Email .

I don't know why dont work and search on Internet but I can't found any similar Answer.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("info@mydomain.ir", "xxx@yahoo.com", "Subject", Message);
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("mail.mydomain.ir",587);
emailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@mydomain.ir", "psw");
emailClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: try specifying port and if you can track your error.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? By the way, you usually need to do `emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` if you're going to use your own credentials.